# Microsoft graph API how to query mails sent to specific address

Tags: python, api, rest, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I want to query my outlook messages for specific adresses that I have sent my mails using the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter) I was able to construct the query below. However, it returns a 400 error code and I do not know how to proceed.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/{user}/messages/?$filter=toRecipients/any(t:t/emailAddress/address eq '{target_email}')
```

for reference, this is how messages are structured:

```
url = https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/{user}/messages/?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq 'john@testdomain.com'

messages = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
message = r['value'][0]

print(message['from'])
print(message['toRecipients'])

{'emailAddress': {'name': 'john', 'address': 'john@testdomain.com'}}
[{'emailAddress': {'name': 'sara', 'address': 'sara@testdomain.com'}}]
```

The idea being that I filter on toRecipients, iterate over all recipients and look for a match in the given emailAdress. How should I do this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toRecipients doesn't work the same as the from address because one is just a property of type microsoft.graph.emailaddress and the other is a collection of those properties (technically this is part of the recipients collection in exchange which also includes CC objects so it's a nested collection).

Those properties are indexed so you can use Search to find messages eg

```
/me/messages?$search="to:blah@blah.com"&$select=subject,toRecipients
```

or you could use participants which include from,to,cc

```
/me/messages?$search="participants:blah@blah.com"
```

Comment: would it also be possible to search for a set of participants? i.e. all customers or all partners.

Comment: what is indexed is the email address so that always has to be the input you can't for instance search for any address within a group or DL

Comment: Also not if I give a group of email addresses as an input? Currently I have two solutions: 1) search for all emails and filter the email addresses or 2) send concurrent requests for all email addresses I want to investigate

Comment: you can use OR in KQL query, depends how large a list your searching on

Comment: between 100-1000 adresses. is this the rights source for KQL? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kql-quick-reference

Comment: No that's the wrong KQL, what exchange uses is Keyword Query Language https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/keyword-queries-and-search-conditions?view=o365-worldwide (what you linked to was Kusto Query Language used in big data). I think there is 4,096 character limit to the query size in KQL